# firebase otp code received but onverificationcomplete() method is not getting called

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

i want the otp sent by Firebase so i can verify that otp entered by user and otp sent by firebase is same or not so i can proceed furthure..through internet i got that by  phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode() i can get otp sent by firebase.but that credential object is in onverificationcomplete() method which is not getting called in my case.

when i run the app i get otp but when i entered that same otp or wrong otp in both cases the next activity get started...

code :

```
    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        // this method is used for getting
        // OTP on user phone number.
        Log.d("piooo", number);
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(number)            // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallBack)           // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    // callback method is called on Phone auth provider.
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            // below line is used for getting OTP code
            // which is sent in phone auth credentials.

            Log.d("piooo","verification completed ");
            codesent = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            Log.d("piooo  firebasecodesent", codesent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // displaying error message with firebase exception.
            Log.d("piooo  fail", "");
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            registerbtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            // when we receive the OTP it
            // contains a unique id which
            Log.d("piooo  code sent", "");
            Log.d("piooo  otp code", s);
            verificationId = s;
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            alertDialog.show();

            otp1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    otp2.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
            otp2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    otp3.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
            otp3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    otp4.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
            otp4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    otp5.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
            otp5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    otp6.requestFocus();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

        }

    };
```

below code is for verify both codes
..if i make  PhoneAuthCredential object here and call method getsmscode() then i get the code which is user inputed code but i want code sent by firebase.

```
// below method is use to verify code from Firebase.
    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        Log.d("piooo  verify code fun", "");
        Log.d("piooo comparison", "code="+code+"codesent="+codesent);

        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        codesent=credential.getSmsCode();
        Log.d("piooo  codesent", codesent);
        if (code.equals(codesent)) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Ready To Go", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            user user = new user("default", user_name.getText().toString(), user_mail.getText().toString(),
                    user_password.getText().toString(), user_mobile_no.getText().toString());
            database.getReference().child("Users").child(authwithmail_uid).setValue(user);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Registration.this, custHomeActivity.class);
                    Log.d("piooo reg uidd maauth", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    i.putExtra("userid", authwithmail_uid);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            Loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            incorrect_otp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           // check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Incorrect OTP!!...Try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            registerbtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'

}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barberr"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    buildFeatures{
//        viewBinding true
//    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
}
```